# android google glass unable to instantiate activity componentInfo

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have no idea what it could be. I searched through my code for like 30 min

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public void onResume(){
    ArrayList<String> voiceResults = getIntent().getExtras()
            .getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

    if (voiceResults.size() >= 1) {
        String infoId = "That is what you said";
        Card ShowDataCard = new Card(this);
        ShowDataCard.setText(voiceResults.get(0));
        //ShowDataCard.setText("Testing");
        ShowDataCard.setInfo(infoId);
        View ShowDataCardView = ShowDataCard.toView();
        setContentView(ShowDataCardView);
    }
    else {
        String mainText = "You did not say anything.";
        String infoId = "Why didn't you say anything?";
        Card ShowDataCard = new Card(this);
        ShowDataCard.setText(mainText);
        ShowDataCard.setInfo(infoId);
        View ShowDataCardView = ShowDataCard.toView();
        setContentView(ShowDataCardView);
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.glass.texttospeech"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.glass.texttospeach.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
            android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger_start" />
     </activity>
</application>
```

So what could it be? The intent filters are correct, the packages are correct, voice trigger is correct.
I am just trying to have it print what you said. I have done it before but it will not work now!

Comment: which exception you are getting? can you post logcat error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are overriding `Activity` methods, don't forget to call super methods.

here you are overriding `onResume()` but not calling super method. call super method like

```
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     // do your work....
 }
```

and use `Override` annotation when you are overriding any method for readability and check for `NullPointException` when you are getting extras from `Intent`. `Intent.getExtras...()` will return `null` if there is no mapping found for a given key